# Check if both variables are defined and not empty

Tags: ansible

I'd like to check if my variables are defined and not empty before continuing the execution of my playbook. Is this correct?

```
- name: Check if variable 'var1' and 'var2' are defined and not empty
  fail: msg="Variable 'var1' and/or 'var2' not defined or empty"
  when: (var1 is undefined or not var1) or (var2 is undefined or not var2)

Thanks in advance for the help.
```

Comment: See [Bare variables in conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.8.html#bare-variables-in-conditionals).

Answer (score 0):

```
    - name: output var1 and var2
      debug:
        msg: "var1 -> {{ var1 }}, var2 -> {{ var2 }}"
      when: (var1 is defined and var1) or (var2 is defined and var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```yaml
- name: Check if variable 'var1' and 'var2' are defined and not empty
  fail:
    msg: "Variable 'var1' and/or 'var2' not defined or empty"
  when: (var1|default('')|length == 0) or
        (var2|default('')|length == 0)
```

Comment: @Z.Liu : What I want to accomplish is stop the playbook if var1 or var2 is not defined or empty. The test in my example looks correct to me, can you confirm?

Comment: Clever method Vladimir, hadn't thought of doing it that way! However, technically the variables are never undefined as they are set to an empty string by default

Comment: @Juntao: Re: *`" technically the variables are never undefined as they are set to an empty string by default `"*. What's wrong with this? It's not an assignment. If a variable is undefined it will stay undefined after the test.